# Python prints lines differently in Windows and Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I tried to recreate the messages from the beginning of The Matrix. It worked fine in Colab, Windows Python shows nothing for a few seconds and then prints the whole Text at once.
Deleting the `if delete == 1:` block does not help.

```
def ghostwriter(string, delete):
  import time
  seq = []
  for i in range(len(string)):
    seq.append(string[i])
  for i in seq:
    print(i, sep="", end="")
    time.sleep(0.2)
  time.sleep(3)
  if delete == 1:
    for i in seq:
      print("\b", sep="", end="")

message = {"Wake up, Neo...":1,"The Matrix has you...":1, "Follow the white rabbit.": 1, "Knock, knock, Neo.": 0}
for string in message:
  ghostwriter(string, message[string])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to flush the output buffer after each print command, see **flush=True** below

```
def ghostwriter(string, delete):
  import time
  seq = []
  for i in range(len(string)):
    seq.append(string[i])
  for i in seq:
    print(i, sep="", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.2)
  time.sleep(3)
  if delete == 1:
    for i in seq:
      print("\b", sep="", end="")

message = {"Wake up, Neo...":1,"The Matrix has you...":1, "Follow the white rabbit.": 1, "Knock, knock, Neo.": 0}
for string in message:
  ghostwriter(string, message[string])
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Marcel Preda's answer I was able to modify the code and also remove the "overwrite-effect". Now it's working.

```
    def ghostwriter(string, delete):
  import time
  seq = []
  for i in range(len(string)):
    seq.append(string[i])
  for i in seq:
    print(i, sep="", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.2)
  time.sleep(3)
  if delete == 1:
    print("\r", sep="", end="")
    print(" "*len(seq), sep="", end="")
    print("\r", sep="", end="")

message = {"Wake up, Neo...":1,"The Matrix has you...":1, "Follow the white rabbit.": 1, "Knock, knock, Neo.": 0}
for string in message:
  ghostwriter(string, message[string])
```